# How to stop SoundCloud from playing related tracks?

Tags: soundcloud

SoundCloud consistently starts playing related tracks or the next playlist once it reaches the end of the currently running playlist. Is there any way to stop that behavior from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been switching back to classic mode before launching playlists. I only have to click "Switch back to classic" from the wrench menu in the top right of the site.

**Update with new solution**: The layout has considerably changed since this question was asked. There is now a little playlist button at most bottom left corner next to the current track. Once clicked, it brings a menu of the playlist/queue and a large button to switch on or off autoplay.

[image: screenshot of interface]

Comment: Where do you have to click? Perhaps you can add a screenshot? And why did you switch back?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Too late of an answer but the option used to be under the wrench tool on the desktop site. But they have decided to  switch entirely to the new UI instead. Only extensions can do the trick now.

Comment: Here is a userscript which does this automatically: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/388427-soundcloud-disable-autoplay-station

Comment: when page is refreshed it resets to on by ......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 5):

SoundCloud doesn't have any option to disable [continuous play](http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/527379-what-is-continuous-play-). Therefore you need to install a browser extension.

Chrome:

- Install [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)
- Then http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/160271

Firefox:

- Install https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/soundcloud-continuous-play-/

([Source](http://forum.djtechtools.com/showthread.php?t=70840))

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work. "Seems that the folks from soundcloud changed something under the hood. Cause i'm too busy and/or lazy i'll stop maintaining the script." -- [says Andreas J. Schwarz](http://userscripts-mirror.org/topics/123835), script author.

Answer (score 0):

As it happens, SoundCloud consistently starts playing related tracks or the next playlist once it reaches the end. The currently running playlist is there.

Answer (score -1):

The new Soundcloud have a II button that stops the music and you can choose witch music to listen later without any soundcloud music playing at the background.

Answer (score -4):

their is an option to stop it but on on phone but once done on a phone as long as you was sign into your soundcloud profile it was stop auto play related track on all of your devices on that account you may be able to do it on a pc but i could find it